# Should I attach my published paper to an e-mail when following up with a professor about a PhD position?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I have written a professor from the USA about a Ph.D. position with my CV. He replied saying its excellent and I should apply in the next fall. Now I have some queries which I will ask him in my next mail and one of my paper has been published today in a very good journal (which I wrote 'submitted' in my CV). Should I include my paper in my next mail saying you can have a look? Will it add extra value or a good impression?

Comment: Are you just trying to make a good impression, or are you actually looking for feedback on your work? Either way, you should be clear about why you're sending him the paper, as "can you have a look?" gives no indication about what you're hoping to achieve from the exchange.

Comment: Is there a problem with attaching the pdf? I didn't think that would be a big issue?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you question meant mail as in email or snail mail...

Comment: Why are you emailing him again?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I find the whole discussion in the comments and the other answer rather strange. There are two options:

- The professor doesn't care about reading the paper. If you sent the paper attached to the email, he can just ignore it.
- The professor wants to read the paper. If you attached it, perfect. If you didn't, either he has to go look for it on the journal's website, log in the publisher's website because many don't do IP-based authentication anymore, and eventually find the "PDF" button behind all the crap that publishers put on journals' website these days; or ask you to send it to him in case it's not public yet (e.g. it was *accepted* today and it will be months before the journal even mentions it publicly) or his university doesn't have a subscription to the journal. That's a complete waste of time.

We're in 2019. Getting a 5 MB attachment in one email is completely insignificant. If the professor is on a roaming data plan in Belize and hasn't set his email client to not download attachments automatically, it's his own fault, and he will rack up hundreds of dollars in charges anyway from all the email a professor routinely gets every day.

My opinion: write your email with your additional queries and so on, and conclude with something like "By the way, the paper 'XXX' that was listed as submitted on my CV is now accepted in journal 'JJJ'. I have attached it to this email in case you would like to take a look." Unobstructive, no pressure.

Comment: Well, hey, even if you find it strange, I'm someone who gets emails from potential PhD students and attachments annoy me. We're in 2019. We don't have to attach every single thing to an email when the internet is right there.

Answer (score 1):

Just send the link with a "By the way, if you are interested in seeing more of my work, I have just had this paper published in X journal: LINK"

Comment: Or in the case that the paper isn't online, just include a statement that the paper has been published and give its title and the journal ref, offering to send a copy if requested. But wait for the request.